# Load file in Colab with Matplotlib

Tags: google-colaboratory

When I use this code to import a data into Colab, it gives me the following error.

```py
import pandas as pd
shirts = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\hp\Desktop\wine.data")
```

---

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\wine.data'
```

I cannot understand because the file is on my desktop!
Can someone help me?

Comment: https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb